# Building web-service to make screenshots of pages

Tags: python, apache, webkit, gtk

Im building an online service that can make screenshots of web-pages and return it to user like an image. How it works:

1) I create virtual framebuffer for X server - for further dont create real windows

2) note in environment variables what display is to use

3) create child process (otherwise previous point will not make effect)

4) in child process create webkit.WebView(), "show" the window and load web-page

5) when I get notification about page is fully loaded - I make screenshot and save it to the file (it is only on this step of project, also - how to return it to user's browser? I know about `Content type: image/png`, but further - gtk.gdk.Pixbuf.save(stdout_file_name)? )

**So! The problem!** If I run it from the console `python parent.cgi` - everything is perfect, but if I open `parent.cgi` (server runs `apache2`) in web browser - then in *real browser* page trying to load infinitely, and in processes on server I see `Xvfb` appeared and plus three(it is obviously and correct) `python` process:

```
python return_picture.cgi
python /home/argon/www/wool/cgi-bin/parent.cgi
bash/sh -c python return_picture.cgi
```

**The code:**

**parent.cgi:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk,webkit,gobject,sys,os,time,subprocess,logging
import cgitb,cgi
import signal
cgitb.enable()

logging.basicConfig(format = u'%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s', level = logging.INFO, filename = u'mylog.log')
logging.critical('ONE MORE TIME')
print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print '' #it is importantly required

class writer(object):
    def write(self, data):
        logging.critical(data)

sys.stdout = writer()
sys.stderr = writer()
class XServer():
    def __init__(self, silence_xvfb=True, display='1', screen='0', xvfb_timeout=3):
        self.pidfile = '/tmp/.X%s-lock' % display
        redirect = '> /dev/null 2>&1'
        redirect = ''
        if not silence_xvfb:
            redirect = ''
        cmd = ' '.join(['Xvfb', ':'+display, '-screen', screen, '1600x1200x24', redirect])
        if(os.path.isfile(self.pidfile)):
            self._kill_xvfb()
        #os.system(cmd+' &')
        subprocess.Popen(cmd+' &', shell=True) #works througth filenodes thats why it is impossible to redirect to log - overriding of file.write() does not make sense
        print 'XVFB STARTED'
        self.xvfb = True
        start = time.time()
        while(True):
            diff = time.time() - start
            if(diff > xvfb_timeout):
                raise SystemError("Timed-Out waiting for Xvfb to start - {0} sec".format(xvfb_timeout))
            if(os.path.isfile(self.pidfile)):
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(0.05)

        os.putenv('DISPLAY', ':%s' % display)

    def _kill_xvfb(self):
        pid = int(open(self.pidfile).read().strip())
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
        print 'KILLED'

    def __del__(self):
        # Kill the frame buffer
        if(self.xvfb):
            self._kill_xvfb()

xserver = XServer()

logging.debug('lets create child')
child = subprocess.Popen("python return_picture.cgi",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
s=child.stdout.readline()
print 'there again'
```

**return_picture.cgi:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from blessings import Terminal
import gtk,webkit,gobject,sys,os,time,signal,logging
import cgitb,cgi

cgitb.enable()
t = Terminal()
logging.basicConfig(format = u'%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s', level = logging.DEBUG, filename = u'mylog.log')

class writer(object):
    def write(self, data):
        logging.critical(data)

sys.stdout = writer()
sys.stderr = writer()
logging.debug('IN CHILD')
#print "Content-Type: image/png"
#print "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
#print '' #it is importantly required
#print 'hello'
web=webkit.WebView()
win=gtk.Window()
index = 0
finished = False
def finished_cb(web_view,sig,res):
    global finished
    global index
    index += 1
    #print index,': ',
    status = web_view.get_property("load-status").value_name
    logging.debug(str(index)+': '+status)
    if "FINISH" in status and not finished:
        finished = True
        gobject.timeout_add(500,drawWindow)
        print 'timeout'
        return

sig2= "resource-load-finished"
web.connect(sig2, finished_cb)
url = 'http://google.com/'
web.open(url)

win.add(web)

def drawWindow():
    width, height = win.get_size()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)

    screenshot = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(win.window, win.get_colormap(), 
                                          0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
    ret = screenshot.subpixbuf(0,0,300,20)
    ret = screenshot
    stdot_filename = os.readlink('/proc/self/fd/0') 
    print stdot_filename
    #screenshot.save(stdot_filename, 'png')

    gtk.main_quit()
    screenshot.save('screenshot.png', 'png')
    print 'screenshot saved'
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decouple the requests for screenshots from their generation.

Have the webpage insert the URLs to take screenshots of into a queue. Have a process pulling items out of this queue and running the screenshot generation script.

This way the web browser doesn't wait for the screenshot process to run (which may just fail anyway), you can handle duplicate requests easily, and you don't overwhelm your server launching more WebKit instances than it can run at the same time.

That's how I do it at http://bookmarkly.com

Comment: thanks! how to organize it? should I make daemon? and then how to communicate with it? with sockets?

Comment: Everything communicates with only the queue. You can use any number of databases or queue servers for that.